# "Medium" specifically applied to width, corresponding with narrow or wide

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "medium", specifically applying to the width of something?  I'm looking something that corresponds with "narrow" or "wide", but not communicating either of those extremes.

For example, you could say in a sentence:

"This bridge is narrow"
"This bridge is [what?]"
"This bridge is wide"

Comment: The absence of an adjective might do it. A _wide_ road is wide, a _narrow_ one is narrow, a _road_ implies a normal size. It will depend on context.

Comment: I'm trying to name three objects, so I definitely need the adjective.  The absence implies a variable width, in this case.

Comment: Normal? Average? Variable? Standard? PLease give us some more context, [edit] your question and explain how this could be used in a sentence (bearing in mind that variable naming is [off topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here)

Comment: *Medium-width*?

Comment: Take a look at Fillmore's [Deixis Lecture 2, "Space"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well shoes are sold in narrow, [**average** / **medium**] and wide.  I can't think of a more used sizing than shoes for narrow and wide and I am sure an industry that revolves around 18 billion feet is trying to use the right words for its product.

Comment: Wow, we're up to 9 billion already? ;)

Comment: I added a slight buffer for dolls!

Comment: I've seen dogs wearing shoes before, too.

Comment: @Jonah - damn I might have been way under on my estimate then.  And do horseshoes count?  Wow I might be off a few billion.

Comment: We need to go deeper 8|